# PWM stock amd cpu fan makes annoying squealing sound

Tags: cpu, bios, fan

I have 4 pin cpu fan and when I change cpu fan mode from PWM to voltage the annoying squealing sound stops.

Can I just leave 4 pin cpu fan on voltage mode? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Is it an electronic whistling noise? Or a mechanical squeal like the bearings are failing?

Comment: I don't think it's mechanical because on the same rpm in voltage mode the sound is gone. The annoying sound occurs only in pwm mode.

Comment: OK, sounds like a capacitor whine from over-voltage.

Comment: Yep, so it's psu? It's a new build.

Answer (score 0):

PWM motor control effectively turns the motor on and off very quickly.  It can certainly be damaging if the motor isn't designed for it and / or the filtering between the PWM module and the motor isn't correct to provide the motor a smoother signal.  This On / Off cycling can cause rattles or squeals due to mechanical components moving around in whatever tiny clearances they have.  Squeals are just very fast rattles.

Voltage control effectively takes up those clearances one time and tends to hold the components in that position while they are running.

Cooling fans (like any DC motor) should run fine when the voltage is adjusted to create speed differences.  The farther away from the "normal" voltage for the motor you get, the higher the required current is and the lower the power output from the motor will be.  Different motors are tolerant of different ranges around their standard voltage.

TLDR: Voltage mode should be fine, but you'll get the best long-term results if you stay away from extreme speed adjustments.